# TabControl customization

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol

[image]

How to customize TabControl? TextBox should be aligned to the right and it should be on the same line with tab items. TextBox is also a filter for each tab item content and it should save its state during the tabs switching (e.g. if we enter "123" into the TextBox when TabItem1 has been selected, then we select TabItem2 and enter "abc", now when we select TabItem1 again, TextBox should contains "123").
Or it is better not to use TabControl element in this case?

Comment: If the filter is specific to the tab then why not put it IN the tab?

Comment: Unfortunately it is a requirement to have such a design.

Comment: Let me guess?  End users are doing UI design.

Comment: Customer wants this UI. He has provided a mockup and I should implement it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a start

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="TextBox"/>
    <TabControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <TabItem Header="Tab Item 2"/>
        <TabItem Header="Tab Item 2"/>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

But you are going to have serious problem when you size the Window down and the tab headers cover the text box.

You are going to need to either build a custom tab control or modify the existing.

That UI design is hard to implement as cannot use standard controls.
Hope this is by the hour.